# Interaction between parent page and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, interaction

I need to drag'n'drop items from parent page to the iframe. When I drop item into iframe, I need to call some events.

Is there any way how to interact parent page with iframe using javascript?

Comment: Is it necessary to be an iframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section to learn how to ask a proper question.